Nelson-Aalen cumulative hazard causing multicollinearity when performing mice in R
I am performing survival analysis and fairly new to multiple imputation and would be grateful for any insights/expertise with respect to this issue.
I have large database and need to impute 2 variables which have 5% missing.
In total my predictor matrix has 12 covariates including the event indicator and Nelson-Aalen cumulative hazard (as per Royston & White).
When I run the imputation with the Nelson-Aalen hazard in the predictor matrix I get a logged event
imp =mice(study_data, method=meth, predictorMatrix=predM, m=2, maxit=10, seed=12345)

head(imp$loggedEvents, 10)
   it im     dep meth                                                       out
1   1  1   smoke  pmm                                               cumhaz_prim
2   1  1 bmi_cat  pmm                                               cumhaz_prim
3   1  1 edu_cat  pmm All predictors are constant or have too high correlation.
4   1  2   smoke  pmm                                               cumhaz_prim
5   1  2 bmi_cat  pmm                                               cumhaz_prim
6   1  2 edu_cat  pmm All predictors are constant or have too high correlation.
7   2  1   smoke  pmm                                               cumhaz_prim
8   2  1 bmi_cat  pmm                                               cumhaz_prim
9   2  1 edu_cat  pmm All predictors are constant or have too high correlation.
10  2  2   smoke  pmm                                               cumhaz_prim

However, when I run the model without the Nelson-Aalen hazard function, my multiple imputation works fine with no logged events.
I have tried adding a ridge penalty=0.01 after reading Stef Van Buuren's very informative book (Flexible Imputation Methods) however this strategy did not work.
Not sure how to proceed as from my reading of the literature, it is recommended to use the cumulative hazard AND event indicator when performing multiple imputation for survival data.
Thank you for your help.
*Note - ran 2 imputations because I was just testing this code but I plan to do 10 imputations.
